# In which episode does Rei Ayanami have a life reflection dialogue?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

In which episode of Neon Genesis Evangelion does Rei Ayanami have a long dialogue, where she reflects on life saying things like "Who am I? What am I? What am I?". There are pictures of houses and in the background with some quiet eerie music you hear her voice.

I can't seem to find this scene that easily, and I really wanted to write the dialogue down.

Answer (score 4):

It was episode 14 if i recall right

http://wiki.evageeks.org/Episode_14

Comment: And to go with it, an Analysis of the monologue:  [Rei's Poem/Monologue, an Analysys](http://wiki.evageeks.org/Theory_and_Analysis:Rei's_Monologue)